# Passing a variable to angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, filter

I'm wondering, why passing a simple variable as the parameter to the filter is not working:

Javascript:

```
var Test = Test || {};
Test.Constants = {};
Test.Constants.DateFormat = 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm';

function Main($scope){
    $scope.date = new Date();
    $scope.format = 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm';
    $scope.format2 = Test.Constants.DateFormat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    {{date}}<br>  // "2016-06-13T10:29:49.935Z"
    {{date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm'}}<br>  // 13/06/2016 02:29
    {{date | date: format}}<br>  // 13/06/2016 02:29
    {{date | date: format2}}<br>  // 13/06/2016 02:29
    {{date | date: Test.Constants.DateFormat}}  // Jun 13, 2016
</div>
```

Why the last one is not formatted?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried passing `$scope.format2` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test` is not defined on the scope and therefore not available in the binding.

You can read a little about scope vs. global variables here: http://jacopretorius.net/2015/04/working-with-global-variables-in-angularjs.html

> The key here is how Angular interprets the expressions between the
>   curly braces. You might expect Angular to do a simple eval on the
>   code, but that is not the case - Angular actually uses JavaScript to
>   parse these JavaScript-like syntax within the context of the current
>   scope.

Answer (score 1):

because you didn't expose `Test` to the scope.

```
$scope.Test = Test;
```

would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a controller variable in html , it should be in $scope. The test you were accessing is a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Test is not defined in your scope. You have to bind Test into $scope.

Answer (score 1):

Define `Test` in scope:

```
function Main($scope) {

    $scope.Test = $scope.Test || {};
    $scope.Test.Constants = {};
    $scope.Test.Constants.DateFormat = 'MMM d, y';

    $scope.date = new Date();
    $scope.format = 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm';
    $scope.format2 = $scope.Test.Constants.DateFormat;
}
```

See working http://jsfiddle.net/da2w2jdL/